# How do I require/use/execute my own module multiple times in express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In my app.js file I need to call my parser.js module at certain points.. I do this my calling
`parser = require('./parser');`
and it works perfectly but it only works **once**.

Whenever I try to call it again it just doesn't do anything. What do I need to change to be able to call my parser.js file multiple times?

thank you.

Comment: You shouldn't `require` mid app. It blocks the thread. Cache it at the beginning **then** run it whenever, pending you're only using it in that file.

Comment: This is what I want but if I just require at the beginning the module gets executed at the wrong time.. it just executes when I run the application instead of in my specific function. is there some way to cache without launching?

Comment: The only way it would fire the module is if you're immediately invoking the function that it exports. Could you paste the `parser` code??

Answer (score 1):

In your parser.js, the functions you want to reuse should be like `exports.fn = function() {}`. Then in your app.js, you require it and call those functions by doing `parser.fn()`

Answer (score 0):

This isn't particularly related to `express`. It's actual a natural behaviour from node.js require module. Whenever you call `require()` it would cache the result of `module.exports`, and subsequent `require` will no longer re-run through the code.

If you want to run the code multiple times, simply export a function. In the Parser.js, so something like

> `module.exports = function() {/* whatever you wish to execute more than once */}`

Then in the `app.js` do this: `var parser = require('./parser');` and simply call `parser()` whenever you wish to use it.